# De-duplicating a table with pairs of Ids

Tags: mysql

I'm stumped by how to do this. I have the following table with rows that I need to de-duplicate:

| BaseCurrencyid | QuoteCurrencyId |
| --- | --- |
| DKK | GBP |
| DKK | GBX |
| DKK | USD |
| GBP | DKK |
| GBP | GBX |
| GBP | USD |
| GBX | DKK |
| GBX | GBP |
| GBX | USD |
| USD | DKK |
| USD | GBP |
| USD | GBX |

De duping involves reducing the table to this:

| BaseCurrencyid | QuoteCurrencyId |
| --- | --- |
| DKK | GBP |
| DKK | GBX |
| DKK | USD |
| GBP | GBX |
| GBP | USD |
| GBX | USD |

i.e. you can have DKK/GBP or GBP/DKK pairs but not both.

Here's a SQL statement that generates the pairs - can anybody amend it to get it working?

```
with 
    cte_currencies as (
        select 'GBP' as CurrencyId union select 'USD' union select 'DKK' union select 'GBX'
    ), cte_combined_crossings as (
        select b.CurrencyId as baseCurrencyId, q.CurrencyId as QuoteCurrencyId from cte_currencies b cross join cte_currencies q where not b.CurrencyId=q.CurrencyId
    )
    
select * from cte_combined_crossings
```

[DbFiddle is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/4zfHqiOQ)

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT` ?  As in, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: @MikeNakis Thanks for the comment - how would that work with the pairs though?

Comment: I note you have not accepted any of the many answers you've received, are you aware of [What to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: Never mind, `SELECT DISTINCT`, I did not correctly understand the problem.  However, I am afraid I am still not sure what is going on. So you say you have a table that you want to de-duplicate, but then you are showing us code that creates the table. So perhaps your question is wrongly asked, and what you want to ask instead is how to create this table without duplicates?

Comment: @MikeNakis that is a very good point - I might be asking the question too late in the process and it is better to not create the duplicates in the first place. I'm still not sure how I'd do that either!

Comment: @Stu a lot of my questions I've answered myself, which I can't vote up. If I haven't voted any of the others up its because they didn't answer the questions...

Comment: Liam, in cases like this it helps to create an SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) and post a link to it in the question, so that people attempting to answer the question can experiment with your data and your query.

Comment: @Liam: You can't upvote your own answer, but you can accept it as the solution. You won't earn any rep for doing so, but it lets people know the question has been answered and also doesn't make it appear as if you're not accepting at all. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for details.